# How would I return all null values from a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to left join two tables (A and B) together and would like to return all values that have a column in table B marked as null in mySQL.

The two tables I am joining are both very large and I am running into an issue where my connection will timeout after 6000 seconds due to the DBMS settings; is there a way to make this query run more efficiently?

Another bit of information: Even if I limit the query to 10 rows, it will still timeout and give me the error code listed below.

```
select * 
from Table_A a
left join Table_B b
on a.field_X = b.field_X
where b.Field_X is null;
```

I am experiencing the following error code: "Error Code 2013. Lost Connection to MySQL server during query."

Side note: I am a new SQL user and may need to ask for clarification on some answers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try a `LIMIT` clause just to see if you are trying to return too many rows and eating into timeout area --  My guess is that you are timing out ..

Comment: Have you put an index on Field_X? Also, if MySQL allows it, you may get better performance from `SELECT * FROM Table_A a WHERE a.field_X NOT IN (SELECT Field_X FROM Table_B);`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And, in addition to the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements, provide the EXPLAIN for the above

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html  There are 3 likely causes.

Comment: Your query is an anti-join. That is, you are selecting all rows from A that do not have a match in B. IS that what you want?

Comment: Right, you are joining on field_x and then filtering for where field_x is null.  NULL does not equal NULL so MySQL is barfing on you.  Is your example correct, or should filter be on a different field?

Comment: In my little experience, `LEFT JOIN` always do full scan on the table left side of the query. And `LIMIT` is always executed at the very end so the query may still run the same as without `LIMIT` then only impose the limit after all the results are in. But I may be wrong

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, the query would be for an anti-join.

Comment: @alexherm Not sure what "NULL Does not equal NULL" means here, sorry. The columns that do not match the left join should return NULL; I'm looking to pull all of those values. I believe that the example I posted is correct based off of my understanding of the logic.

Comment: You have filter of 'where b.Field_X is null' and then you are joining on field_x.  This is the equivalent of joining on NULL = NULL which will never return any records - you cannot compare NULL in this manner.

Comment: @Alexherm This is a left join, so my thoughts are that there would be a situation where a.field_x has a value where b.field_x does not. In this situation, all columns in table_B would come in as "NULL" but a.field_x would still have a value.

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need columns from `a` because the `b` columns are all `null`.  You can write this as:

```
select a.* 
from Table_A a left join
     Table_B b
     on a.field_X = b.field_X
where b.Field_X is null;
```

Then for this query, I recommend an index on `table_b(field_x)`.

Comment: Got it, I tried selecting only the columns from Table A, still hit Error 2013. I will look into indexing table B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
    select * from table_A a where a.field_X not in (select field_x from table_B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the other way around, and reduce your `SELECT` fields if you can:

```
select Table_B.Field_X 
from Table_B b
left join Table_A a
on a.field_X = b.field_X
where a.Field_X is null;
```

Let SQL do its work they way it likes to do it :)  To have a standard left join (where you are looking for rows that do NOT match on the right) is highly optimised if you have the correct indexes